# Spark Multi-threading, Could not serialize object exception

Tags: python, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

> _pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

I'm working in implementing a page rank algorithm in `spark` with a large data frame.

I'm using a `udf` in order to calculate the algorithm:

```
new_pagerank_udf = udf(lambda x,y: new_pagerank(x,pageRankDF,y), FloatType())
```

The function:

```
def new_pagerank(links, current_pr, counters):
  n_pr = 0;
  #for each incoming link to the page calculate the pagerank
  #zip the links and counters to get them both in the loop
  for l, c in zip(links, counters):
    
    
    #get current_pr of the link l
    try:
      current_link_pr=current_pr[current_pr['id']==l].PR.item()
      

    except:
      current_link_pr=0.85/N
        

    n_pr += current_link_pr/c
  new_pr = 0.85/N+0.15*n_pr
  return new_pr
```

pageRankDF:

```
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   id      77 non-null     int64  
 1   PR      77 non-null     float64
```

Where the udf is called:

```
count=0;
display(pageRankPDF)
previous_pr_sum=0
while ((converged(previous_pr_sum,pageRankPDF["PR"].sum())==False) & (count<7)):
    previous_pr_sum=pageRankPDF["PR"].sum()
    NewPageRankDF=ReverseDF.select(
        ReverseDF["id"],
        new_pagerank_udf(ReverseDF["links"],ReverseDF["counters"]).alias("PR"))
    pageRankDF=NewPageRankDF
    display(pageRankDF)
    count=count+1
```

ReverseDF:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- Links: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- counters: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
```

The only way that i have found working is to convert the `spark data frame` to a `pandas` data frame using `.toPandas()`, but is too slow for a large data frame.

Can i fix it without use a `pandas df`?

Comment: You need basic Spark understanding. Or you can stick to `.toPandas()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark: Broadcast variables: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transforamtion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508689/spark-broadcast-variables-it-appears-that-you-are-attempting-to-reference-spar)