# running an sql expression stored in a column using pyspark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to find a way to execute stored sql expression in a column using pyspark. Here is the sample below.

| col1 | col2 | rules |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rule1 | test | when col1 is xxx then 'hello' when col2 is 'yyy' then 'world' |
| rule2 | test1 | when col2 is 'abc' then 'foo' when col1 is null then 'bar' |

after executing the rules column, I want the output to like below.

| col1 | col2 | rules | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rule1 | test | when col1 is 'rule1' then 'hello' when col2 is 'yyy' then 'world' | hello |
| rule2 | test1 | when col2 is 'abc' then 'foo' when col1 is null then 'bar' | null |

I tried selectExpr but it's not working.. any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Not easily at least.

You'll run in to `RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063`. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5063

TL;DR is that code running on executor can not use sc, only the code running on driver is allowed to do so. It's like running `spark.read(...)` inside a UDF, it's not supported.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508689/spark-broadcast-variables-it-appears-that-you-are-attempting-to-reference-spar) also.

---

What you can do is:

```
@udf
def process_sql_expression(rule, c1, c2):
   # logic to parse rule and return c1 or c2
   return ...

df_orig = spark.read(...) # has col1, col2 and rule
new_df = df_orig.select(
              'col1', 
              'col2', 
              'rules', 
              process_sql_expression('rules', 'col1', 'col2').alias('result')
)
```

Gotcha is that "# logic to parse rule and return c1 or c2" can not use `spark` or `sc`. So if you e.g. can find a Java/python lib that can do it for you then you can make it available to all executors by installing it everywhere and then use it in the udf implementation.